# CommitFailedException even when within max.poll.interval.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm very puzzled - or at least I'm lost in Kafka's configuration properties. But I don't understand why this `CommitFailedException` is thrown when I'm trying to commit Offsets. Property `max.poll.interval.ms` is `36000000` (600 minutes) and `consumer.commitSync()` is called about 105 minutes after `consumer.poll()`. Here is the Code we're using:

```
public void run() {
    this.consumer.subscribe("awesome.topic", (ConsumerRebalanceListener) this.consumerRecoveryService);
    try {
        while (!this.closed.get()) {
            try {
                this.consumerRecoveryService.updateSavedPositions();
                ConsumerRecords<String, DeletionCandidate> records = this.consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(this.CONSUMER_POLL_DURATION.intValue()));
                if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                    Map.Entry<Integer, List<RequestForDeletionContext>> result = this.handler.handleNewRequestsForDeletion(convert(records), TransactionBean.Source.KAFKA, false);
                    List<RequestForDeletionContext> requestForDeletionContexts = result.getValue();
                    long transactionId = ((Integer)result.getKey()).intValue();
                    for (RequestForDeletionContext context : requestForDeletionContexts) {
                        ProducerRecord<String, DeletionCandidateReceipt> record = new ProducerRecord(this.DELETION_CANDIDATE_PRODUCER_TOPIC, DeletionCandidatesConverter.convert(context, transactionId));
                        this.producer.send(record);
                    }
                    this.consumer.commitSync();
                }
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                this.consumerRecoveryService.seekToRecover();
            }
        }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        if (!this.closed.get())
            throw e;
    } finally {
        this.consumer.close();
    }
}
```

These are our Properties:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.logAll ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = <has-been-removed-for-posting>
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = my-awesome-group
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 36000000
    max.poll.records = 5000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 60000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = /path/to/user.p12
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = PKCS12
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = /path/to/ca.p12
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = PKCS12
    value.deserializer = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

And this is the detailed Exception which is thrown:
`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add the entire consumer creation properties you used . It seems like your consumer has been kicked out of the group because if too much ```max.poll.interval.ms``` and ```consumer.commitSync()```

Comment: Since you're sending data back to Kafka, using Kafka Streams would be recommended

Comment: Yes, maybe Kafka Streams would be the better approach. But it's legacy code - or even worse: decompiled Bytecode because the maker has gone bankrupt :/ - and changing it is not really an option.